# How to set x-opt-offset when establishing connection to event hub using AMQP to avoid message replay

Tags: azure, amqp, azure-eventhub

My application connects to azure event hub to receive messages and process them. I see that every time I restart my application, all the messages within the retention period gets replayed. I read about offset to avoid this issue and I have a method that sets up connection to an azure event hub as:

```java
    MessageConsumer connect() {
        // set up JNDI context
        BatchEventHubConfig batchEventHubConfig = //MAP CONTAINING CONFIG
        String queueName = "EventHub"
        String connectionFactoryName = "SBCF"
        //Long offset = batchAccountManager.batchStorageManager.batchJobMsgCheckpointService.get(batchEventHubConfig.namespace, batchEventHubConfig.getMessageQueueAddress(partitionInx, true))?.offset
        Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<>()
        hashtable.put("connectionfactory.${connectionFactoryName}", batchEventHubConfig.getAMQPConnectionURI())
        hashtable.put("queue.${queueName}", batchEventHubConfig.getMessageQueueAddress(partitionInx))
        //hashtable.put("apache.org:selector-filter:string", "amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > '${offset}'")
        hashtable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory")
        Context context = new InitialContext(hashtable)

        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactoryName)
        queue = (Destination) context.lookup(queueName)
        connection = factory.createConnection(batchEventHubConfig.sasPolicyName, batchEventHubConfig.sasPolicyKey)
        connection.setExceptionListener(new BatchExceptionListener(eventHubConnection: this))

        connection.start()
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue)
        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(messageListener)
        messageConsumer
    }
```

The commented out code for offset was what I was trying after reading up here : https://azure.github.io/amqpnetlite/articles/azure_eventhubs.html

What is the correct way to set the offset so the messages don't get re-played when the application restart?

Answer (score 2):

Apche QPID does not support AMQP filters ( the underlying Apache Proton J does ) ..

I have patched the AmqpConsumerBuilder.configureSource() method by adding the following lines in the end :

```
Symbol filterKey = Symbol.valueOf("apache.org:selector-filter:string");
UnknownDescribedType filterValue = new UnknownDescribedType(filterKey, String.format("%s > '%s'",amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset", lastOffset));

filters.put(filterKey, filterValue);
```

and it works !

So either you make a fork of Apache QPID and apply this patch ou put the modified class in your class path to override the original ( very bad solution )

Answer (score 0):

It was much easier than I had thought! Found this link : https://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml

So all I had to do was add the filter condition like this:

```
messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset >= '${messageOffset}'")
```

Comment: This didn't work for me and will result in an exception like:  javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset >= '1'

Comment: It must be a valid offset value, if you are starting of with empty queue then the value should be -1.

Comment: When using qpid-jms-client, a filter with a dot in the name, will result in a InvalidSelectorException. You are right about the empty queue. I ran into that as well. But that will result in another error. Using the forked version I showed as answer, works fine with qpid-jms-client

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer of Mourad Zouabi, I created a fork of the qpid-jms repository and changed the AmqpConsumerBuilder class as follows to allow passing the filter to a MessageConsumer:

```
   if (resourceInfo.getSelector() != null && !resourceInfo.getSelector().trim().equals("")) {
        if (resourceInfo.getSelector().startsWith("x-opt-offset") || resourceInfo.getSelector().startsWith("x-opt-enqueued-time")) {
            // support Azure Event HUB filters
            // see: https://azure.github.io/amqpnetlite/articles/azure_eventhubs.html
            Symbol filterKey = Symbol.valueOf("apache.org:selector-filter:string");
            UnknownDescribedType filterValue = new UnknownDescribedType(filterKey,"amqp.annotation." + resourceInfo.getSelector().trim());
            filters.put(filterKey, filterValue);
        } else {
            filters.put(JMS_SELECTOR_SYMBOL, new AmqpJmsSelectorType(resourceInfo.getSelector()));
        }
    }
    if (!filters.isEmpty()) {
        source.setFilter(filters);
    }
```

Now a filter can be passed while creating a MessageConsumer:

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue,  String.format("x-opt-offset > %s", offset));
```

or

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue,  String.format("x-opt-enqueued-time > %s", timeStamp));
```

See https://github.com/ekkelenkamp/qpid-jms for a working fork.